# Implement a portal in Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte

In React you can render a component in a different node using [Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html):

```js
ReactDOM.createPortal( 
  <Component />,
  document.getElementById('id')
);
```

Same for Vue using the [portal-vue](https://github.com/LinusBorg/portal-vue) package.

But is there a way to something similar in Svelte?

```html
<body>
  <Header>
    <Modal /> <!-- Modal is rendered here -->
  </Header>

<!-- But the Modal DOM would be injected at the body end -->
</body>
```

Comment: FYI The general answer to this question would be to just use the DOM methods like you would without any framework. Since Svelte doesn't use a virtual DOM (unlike React or Vue), you don't really need a "portal" :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See this issue : https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/3088

*Portal.svelte*

```html
<script>
import { onMount, onDestroy } from 'svelte'
let ref
let portal

onMount(() => {
  portal = document.createElement('div')
  portal.className = 'portal'
  document.body.appendChild(portal)
  portal.appendChild(ref)
})

onDestroy(() => {
  document.body.removeChild(portal)
})

</script>

<div class="portal-clone">
  <div bind:this={ref}>
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</div>
<style>
  .portal-clone { display: none; }
</style>
```

You can then you it with the following template. Modal will be renderer under `<body/>` :

```html
<Portal>
  <Modal/>
</Portal>
```

Comment: These examples use Svelte actions, another approach that does not require a component, but enhance an existing one:

- https://svelte.dev/repl/86ec36c27be2471f86590e0c18c7198c?version=3.23.2
- https://svelte.dev/repl/79e33c2d7695444b994ba74255bb1387?version=3.24.0

Answer (score 4):

Another solution would be to use the [svelte-portal](https://github.com/romkor/svelte-portal) library:

```html
​<script​>​
  ​import​ ​Portal​ ​from​ ​'svelte-portal'​;​
​</​script​>​

​<​Portal​ ​target​="​body"​>​
    <Modal/>
</​Portal​>​
```