# How to tell svelte bundle where to render in existing page dom

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

We know that it's possible to define which target to render svelte - on build time. But is it possible to tell the bundle were to render on run time (when loading bundle) in the HTML file.

```
<html>
<body>

  <div id="id1"> </div>
  <div id="id2"> </div>

  <script>
      // how to tell the bundle to load at id1 and id2
  </script>

<script defer src='/mycustomsveltething/bundle.js'></script>

</body>
</html>
```

On build time we don't know anything about the context the svelte-app is loaded, not even the id.

Usecases

We build a form in svelte. Now we want to add it to a serverside rendered page, many serverside rendered pages or even multiple times on one serverside rendered page.

Comment: I guess that what you need is a Portal component that render the node in a specific node. If it's the case you should have a look to this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/62733094/8583669.

Comment: I cant see that work. I need to tell the bundle where to load from the hosting HTML page. Ive updated question

Comment: Are you looking for https://svelte.dev/tutorial/making-an-app ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you where it will have to render the moment it has been rendered by the server (so your backend can somehow figure this out) you can create a sort of configuration object in the page:

```html
<script>
  window.myapp.renderTarget = 'id1';
</script>
<script defer src='/mycustomsveltething/bundle.js'></script>
```

and than use this value in the app itself:

```js
// main.js
import App from './App.svelte';

const app = new App({
    target: window.myapp.renderTarget
});

export default app;
```

Comment: great idea! I ended up setting a prop from the window var so svelte would know what feature component to render - works a treat!

Answer (score 0):

it helped me.
in html

```
<script defer src='/mycustomsveltething/bundle.js'></script>
```

and place where i need

```
<div id="id1"></div>
```

and in js

```
import App from './App.svelte';
const app = new App({
    target: document.querySelector('#id1'),
    props: {
        name: 'world'
    }
});
export default app;
```

https://svelte.dev/docs#Client-side_component_API